# WooCommerce get products based on the taxonomy

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to modify the WooCommerce product query because I want to filter the shown products on the shop pages based on the taxonomies for each product. So what I've tried is this here:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter', 10, 2 );
function filter( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on category pages
    if ( ! is_product_category() ) {
        return $meta_query;
    }

    $tags_array[] = 'ABCSD';

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'product_tag',
        'value'   => $tags_array,
        'compare' => 'EXIST'
    );

    return $meta_query;
}
```

So I just want to display all products which have the taxonomy ABCSD in it.
The code is placed in my functions.php. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You should use the `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` filter, and check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) if you need help with *taxonomy queries* (i.e. `tax_query`). I'd also rename '$meta_query' to '$tax_query' since the latter is more relevant...

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667469/display-one-category-on-the-shop-page-woocommerce